# Can someone please help me translate the writing on this dizi?

Tags: translation

I was looking at this dizi and was just wondering if someone could help me translate the writing :)[image]

Comment: Simplified Chinese: 牧童归去横牛背，短笛无腔信口吹。

Answer (score 1):

***《村晚》 雷震***

草滿池塘水滿陂，山銜落日浸寒漪。

**牧童歸去橫牛背，短笛無腔信口吹。**

---

***Rural Scene at Dusk
By Lei Zhen***

Green grass overgrows the shore of the brimming pool;

The sun pecked by hills sinks into ripples cool.

**A cowherd comes back astride on a buffalo**;

**He blows on his short flute a tune he may not know.**

Please refer to:[詩歌](http://www.kekenet.com/kouyi/201704/502392.shtml)

The English translation has already explain the meaning. I just skip for the explanation part. :) hope you enjoy this.

Comment: Just a reminder, I am using Traditional Chinese Characters for the poem translation. I think that it is suitable to be used when translating or writing the Old Chinese.

Comment: Do you really think 橫 should translate to astride? I would think it meant horizontal, not sitting upright. Also "a tune he may not know" is very poetic. Perhaps you translate more with the poetic beauty in mind?